# Puppeteer / Nodejs , How to wait for event conditions to be met

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm fairly new to nodejs and I am using puppeteer to automate some browsing , but I am getting a bit lost with the complexity of a certain scenario.

I am clicking a button , and it will search some records ( using ajax ) and put the result on the page.

Wait for Response / request doesn't really fit , because I am waiting for 2-3 requests depending on the type of search - and the response URL's are exactly the same for each. So , I guess I want to wait for 3 url responses of this particular URL to be complete.

Maybe I need to rethink this , or maybe I am close?  The promise always times out even though it seems to be increasing the responseCount

```
async function intercepted(resp) {
  if (resp.url().includes('/ajaxpro/')) {
    return 1
  }
  return 0
}

let responseCount = 0
page.on('response', async resp => {
  responseCount += await intercepted(resp)
})
const getResponse = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(responseCount > 3), 60000)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the condition after each response is received.

```
async function intercepted(resp) {
  if (resp.url().includes('/ajaxpro/')) {
    return 1
  }
  return 0
}

let responseCount = 0
page.on('response', async resp => {
  let isTargetSearch = await intercepted(resp);
  responseCount += isTargetSearch;

  // - The current response is what we are looking for
  // - and reached 3 times.
  if(isTargetSearch && responseCount == 3) {
    // Do what you need to do here
  }
})
```

Comment: Sorry , that doesn't answer my question. I think you might be missing what I am trying to achieve.  the page.on is an asynchronous event that happens when a response is received from the page object.  I want to "pause"  until the responseCount > 3 , but outside that code - because that code only responds to activity in the browser - not in relation to the sequence of code.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you want to wait for the page to be loaded, and **then** perform the click & search, is this right?

Comment: Thanks @Neverever.  Not quite that simple.  the page is loaded , and we are using ajax calls - so we are using wait for response.  The problem is , there are multiple reponses , and they are all the same , so we have to wait for 3 of the same responses to complete before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have to wait until a certain number of responses have been intercepted but wait until the results from those AJAX calls have rendered *something* on the page (wait for **visual** results). In that case, you would be doing a `page.waitForSelector(selector)`, where the selector is the information that the result of the call render on screen.

When dealing with Puppeteer, I usually find waiting for visible results to be better...

Comment: Sorry @YorkeUtopy , because it is a "filter" , the results of all 3 actions are very similar - and there is nothing specific happaning that is different from the other one.  I actually got the answer , will post it here soon.